# Excepción salta el catch C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un `ActionResult` en el cual se hace llamada a por primera vez al `View`, este metodo llama unos datos en de una API para despues mostrarlos en una tabla en el `View`:

```
[Authorize]
   [HandleError]
    public ActionResult ClasificacionCliente()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:6417/");
            var request = new RestRequest("api/clasificacionCliente", Method.POST);
            request.AddQueryParameter("cnn", cnn);
            var respond = client.Execute(request);
            var modelo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClasificacionCliente>>(respond.Content);
            List<ClasificacionCliente> ListadoClasificacion = new List<ClasificacionCliente>();


            foreach (var item in modelo)
            {
                ClasificacionCliente _item = new ClasificacionCliente();
                _item.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente = item.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente;
                _item.Tipo_Cliente = item.Tipo_Cliente;
                ListadoClasificacion.Add(_item);

            }

            return View(ListadoClasificacion);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error.ErrorData = ex.Message.ToString();
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Si pasa un error en cualquier lado tengo una pagina 500 donde van a dar los errores de 500, resulta que cuando el `ActionResult` pasa todo el bloque, me entra directamente a controlador del 500:

```
public ActionResult Error_500()
    {
        TempData["Error500"] = Error.ErrorData;
        return View();
    }
```

Obviamente como no hay nada en TempData, la pagina no puede ser mostrada y produce un fallo.

**EDICION**

A la hora del breakpoint se ve que hay datos para cuando entre al `View`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregue el código de la vista y el modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya validaste que  **respond** te devuelve algo?

ya probaste hacer un await en la obtención de datos.

```
var respond = client.Execute(request);
```

por lo general cuando obtenemos datos(y mas cuando son externos) es recomendable utilizar await para obligar a que el código no se siga ejecutando hasta que se ejecute esa tarea(al usar await tu me metodo tendria que ser async)

Comment: Si, de hecho cuando llega al return, ya hay datos para el model, estoy utilizando la misma estructura en otra vista para cargar aún mayores datos pero ésta se comporta diferente